# wordpress admin area not loading scripts from plugins

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I can't figure out why none of my plugins can load scripts. I tried three different plugins. This is actually the theme of a client and I just taking over.
[image: details from the console in the admin area]

[image: details from the network area in the admin wordpress]
Do any of you have any idea what could be causing this. I am doing a malware search, and I've already searched this and tried the wp_config (define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false); thing. I appreciate your help. Thanks!

What could it be that is causing all plugin scripts not to load?

Comment: One possibility is that your plugins folder has the wrong permissions.

Comment: permissions are correct...that's not the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check if there isnt mixed content in different protocol that you are acessing in this case. In case if your are acessing in a `http` protocol, check if there is some request to the same domain but in `https` protocol.

[Read more about Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/Mixed_content)

Comment: Nothing shows for mixed content in the security section